# Посчитать количество элементов с дополнительными условиями

Tags: python, dataframe, timestamp

Есть файл csv с двумя столбцами: в первом- даты, во втором некий цифровой код (принимает значение 10,20,30 и тд до 160)
На выходе надо получить аналог сводной таблицы: сгруппированные по коду количество попаданий в некое условие (между двух дат).
Список стартовых дат и конечных, между которыми выбираются значения, завела отдельными переменными.
Написала код использующий вложенные циклы, но считается медленно, тк строк в исходном файле более 200 тыс. Наверняка есть какая-то питоновская магия, как это записать более компактно и с увеличением производительности.

Привожу кусок кода:

```
start_dates_=['15.03.2016','15.06.2016','15.09.2016','15.12.2016','15.03.2017','15.06.2017','15.09.2017','15.12.2017','15.03.2018']

end_dates_=['14.05.2016','14.08.2016','14.11.2016','14.02.2016','14.05.2017','14.08.2017','14.11.2017','14.02.2017','14.05.2018']

start_dates=pd.to_datetime(start_dates_, format="%d.%m.%Y")

end_dates=pd.to_datetime(end_dates_, format="%d.%m.%Y")


count=[] 
a=[] 

df1=pd.read_csv("L:/dataset.csv",sep=";",encoding='ANSI')

df1["Дата включения"]=pd.to_datetime(df1["Дата включения"], format="%d.%m.%Y")

df1["Дата взноса"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Дата взноса"], format="%d.%m.%Y")

data2=list(df1.values)

for z in range(len(start_dates)):

    for j in range(10,161,10):

        m=0

        for i in range(1,len(data2)):

            if data2[i][0]>=start_dates[z] and data2[i][0]<=end_dates[z]:

                if int(data2[i][2])==j:

                    m=m+1

        count.append(m)

    a.append(count)

    count=[]
```

Comment: Хотелось бы файл с данными или его кусок, чтобы можно было запустить у себя на пробу.

Comment: Приведите в вопросе примеры входных и выходных данных [(Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 2):

для ускорения, надо считать в один проход. Для хранения результатов можно применять dict of dict

```
from collections import defaultdict

# формирование тестового набора
date_start_test = [1, 10, 20, 30]
date_end_test = [9, 19, 29, 39]

data2_test = [
    ['date', 'param'],
    [3, 10],
    [4, 20],
    [15, 10],
    [22, 30],
    [22, 40],
    [24, 40],
]
start_dates, end_dates, data2 = [date_start_test, date_end_test, data2_test]

# непосредственно подсчет 
date_pair = list(zip(start_dates, end_dates))
date_counter = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
for row in data2[1:]: # ?вроде csv умеет отдавать данные без заголовков
    data = next(start for start, end in date_pair if start <= row[0] <= end)
    param = row[1]
    date_counter[data][param] += 1

print(date_counter)
```